# Replace with function instead of string with swift regex

Tags: swift, regex

In Javascript, you can [replace a string with a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).  Is there a way do do this in Swift with `NSRegularExpression`?

I want to do the equivalent of

```
"*Hello there*".replace(/(\*).*?(\*)/g, function(match, p1, p2, p3) {
    return "<i>" + p2 + "</i>"
})
```

in Swift because I'm writing a markdown parser.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1413740-stringbyreplacingmatches

Comment: @Sweeper That doesn't let me use a function as the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't but you can solve your issue inserting the tags and removing the reference character afterwards:

```
let str = "*Hello there*"
let result = str
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\*.*?\\*)", with: "<i>"+"$1"+"</i>", options: .regularExpression)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\*(.*?)\\*", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
print(result)  //  "<i>Hello there</i>"
```